# Wicket - confirmation on panel replace / remove to save unsaved data

Tags: java, replace, wicket, panel, confirmation

i have a Wicket SPA web application where i want the user to confirm that on panel panel replace / remove he wants the data entered in the panel saved or not?
My app structur looks like this

```
<body>
 <nav>
  <a wicket:id="home">Home</a>
  <a wicket:id="documents">Documents</a>
  <a wicket:id="user">Users</a>
  <a wicket:id="logout">Logout</a>
 </nav>
 <main wicket:id="panel"></main>
</body>
```

Now have a `addDocumentPanel` which is replaced into the `wicket:id='panel'` when the user clicks somewhere 'Add new Document'. In this panel the user has to fill several fields in a formular. Now when the user clicks on for example Home the `addDocumentPanel` is replaced by a `homePanel`. When this happens i want to ask the user if he wants to save unsaved data.

A good place to do it SOLID is the [onRemove()](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#onRemove%28%29) function of the `Panel` but here i dont have any `AjaxRequestTarget` or other things to ask user either through JavaScript or wickets ModalWindow.

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: If you use an AjaxButton or AjaxLink you should be able to use the AjaxRequestTarget to call a confirmation dialog prior to replacing your panel.  If you post some more of your code someone may be able to provide a more complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add a behavior to all of the navigation links that when clicked does a simple logic of checking if the form contains any dirty (unsaved) data. I guess this can be done on the client side without a server roundtrip and upon finding the form is dirty, you can show a window.alert dialog to the user.

A more heavy approach is to use your own AjaxLink subclass for the navigation links and in the onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) handler do the ModalWindow magic. This however causes your links to contain non-bookmarkable urls. If it's not a concern (this is an internal application, not internet facing web site), then this may work as well.

Comment: I'm doing it right now with behaviors like you say and with modal windows - but i dont like it. I also use modal windows. In order to have all links 'with confirmation' i have to have this modal window in my `BasePage` adn save entities from there. That's ugly.

Comment: You can change the content of a ModalWindow on the fly when the behavior handles the request. We usually add a ModalWindow to each page upon construction, and when an event handler wants to display it, then we populate the ModalWindow's content with whatever the link wants to display, and then add it the ajax response.